# SPFx WebPart - SP.Runtime.js evaluation takes a long time

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, jsom

I have an existing JSOM web-part which reference the SPO runtime:

```
,
    "sp-runtime": {
      "path": "https://abc/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js",
      "globalName": "SP",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "microsoft-ajax"
      ]
    },
    "sharepoint": {
      "path": "https://abc/_layouts/15/SP.js",
      "globalName": "SP",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "sp-runtime"
      ]
    },
    "sharepoint-doc-mgmt": {
      "path": "https://abc/_layouts/15/SP.DocumentManagement.js",
      "globalName": "SP",
      "globalDependencies": [
        "sharepoint"
      ]
    }
```

I then reference it:

```
require("sp-init");
require("microsoft-ajax");
require("sp-runtime");
require("sharepoint");
```

The part works as desired but initial load takes over a minute. After generating a performance report, I see that SP.Runtime.js script evaluation takes over a minute:

[image]

I am not sure how to reference the runtime so as to avoid the delay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to load the libraries directly.

```
SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/init.js', {
      globalExportsName: '$_global_init'
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=sp.res&culture=en-us', {
        globalExportsName: 'Sys'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/SP.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })            
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/sp.init.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'SP'
      });
    })  
    .then((): Promise<{}> => {
      return SPComponentLoader.loadScript('/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'Strings'
      });
    })
```